# Troubles importing custom widget using QUILoader Pyside6

Tags: python, user-interface, qt-designer, pyside6

I am trying to code a GUI for controller of motorized stages in python using the PySide6 module.
My controller can have up to three stages connected to it.
I would like to create a "stage window" similar for any stages and a "controller window" in which I can integrate the "stage window" individually.

I learned that we can directly import the ui file by using QUILoader. I what to use this method because I use QtDesigner to create my GUI and it let me the possibility of modifing it directly without having to regenerate py files or something else.

I already make the differents windows but I can't integrate the "stage window" in the "controller window" and i don't understand what's wrong in the code.

I have create in the "controller window" an empty widget called "widgetPlatineX" in which I add an instantiate object by the class of my platine.
There is no error in the console, the "controller window" is showing up correctly but the widget where the "stage window" should appears is maintained empty.

Here is the code for the "stage window" :

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

loader = QUiLoader()

dic_valeur = {0:0.01, 1:0.05, 2:0.1, 3:0.5, 4:1, 5:5}

class MainWindowPlatine(QtWidgets.QWidget): #An object wrapping around our ui
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = loader.load("Platine/Ui_main_window_platine.ui", MainWindowPlatine)
        self.parent = parent
        self.change_position()
        self.ui.horizontalSliderRelatif.valueChanged.connect(self.change_position)

    def show(self):
        self.ui.show()

    def change_position(self):
        int = self.ui.horizontalSliderRelatif.value()
        valeur = str(dic_valeur[int])
        self.ui.lineEditValeurRelatif.setText(valeur)

    def load(self, chemin):
        self.ui = loader.load(chemin)
```

and here the "controller window" :

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from Platine.main_window_platine import MainWindowPlatine

loader = QUiLoader()

class MainWindowPorteEchantillon(QtWidgets.QWidget): #An object wrapping around our ui
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = loader.load("Ui_main_window_porte_echantillon.ui", None)
        self.PlatineX = MainWindowPlatine()

        layout_platineX = QHBoxLayout()
        layout_platineX.addWidget(self.PlatineX)
        self.ui.widgetPlatineX.setLayout(layout_platineX)

    def show(self):
        self.ui.show()
```

One thing to know is that the files of the "stage window" is in a sub-folder of the "controller window" folder.

Can someone explain me what's wrong with the code or help me find a way to pass through this trouble ?
Even if it's an other way of doing it.

My purpose is to add a widget/window I have already created in another one.

Comment: It seems you're misunderstanding how to use QWidget classes with QUiLoader. In fact, those `MainWindowPlatine` and `MainWindowPorteEchantillon` subclasses are quite useless right now: you could've done the same with a basic python `object` subclass. You should add the loaded UI form in the current QWidget instance (`self`), not use it as a separate object.

Comment: I'm trying to do that as a "training". The two windows will both have more methods and functions.

Comment: At the end I would have a big window in which I will integrate all of my modules. Each module will correspond to a unique window so I could configure my mainWindow as I what. There is no possibility to use QUiLoader as I want ?